# Python: Looping over dataset and isolating low, high and other data

Tags: python

Using Python 3.
I have some daily financial data in a csv file and load the file to a list:

```
               #date,            open,   high,   low,   close
price_data = [['2018-05-05',    '2.75', '2.05', '2.67', '2.92'],
              ['2018-05-08',    '2.93', '2.97', '2.79', '2.84'],
              ['2018-05-09',    '2.46', '2.74', '2.45', '2.69'],
              ['2018-05-10',    '2.69', '2.69', '2.21', '2.33']]
```

The data goes back years.

I would like to make monthly data out of it: Find the first day of each month, pick the first item (the open), find the last day of the month, pick the last item (the close) and then find the min and the max in between the first and last dates. I would like to return open, high, low and close for each month.

However, my implementation falls short.

I am looping over the list and am finding when the month increments, no problem. That's easy. Taking the open is easy too.

Then I though I'd pick the highs and lows if the high is bigger in the next line, I shall use that instead.

```
trading_day_l = []
month_open_l = []
month_close_l = []
month_high_l = []
month_low_l = []
for i in range(2, len(price_data)):
    day = price_data[i][0].split('-')
    prev_day = price_data[i - 1][0].split('-')
    month = int(day[1])
    prev_month = int(prev_day[1])
       if month > prev_month or (month == 1 and prev_month == 12):  # First trading day.
          first_trading_day_date = price_data[i][0]
          trading_day_l.append(first_trading_day_date) #escape the data from loop
          month_open = price_data[i][1]
          month_open_l.append(month_open) #escape the data from loop
          month_high = price_data[i][2]
          month_low = price_data[i][3]
          month_close = price_data[i][4]
      #below fails I think:  
      if month == prev_month:
          if price_data[i][2] > price_data[i - 1][2]:
              month_high = price_data[i][2]
          if price_data[i][3] < price_data[i - 1][3]:
              month_low = price_data[i][3]
```

Something's messed up though and after some hours spend and failed I need to concede defeat and ask for help. What am I missing?

Cheers!

Comment: Please post the expected output

Comment: I'd recommend reading this data in via pandas (`import pandas as pd`   `data = pd.read_csv(filename, ...)`). This libraray has powerful data analysis algorithms implemented including resampling of time indices.

Comment: What you are missing is that you are parsing the dates yourself. Date arithmetic is hard to get right and it is incidental to the problem you are trying to solve. Convert the date strings to `datetime`s (module `datetime`) and use `dateutil` to ease work with differences.

Comment: Just for the sake of interest: I think there's an error in the data. At least I do not understand why the high-value of '2018-05-05' is in fact the minimum of the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pandas approach I mentioned in the comment.

```
import pandas as pd
```

After importing the data into a pandas dataframe via sth like

```
df = pd.read_csv('/wherever/file/may/roam/filename', _some_kwargs_depending_on_your_csv_layout_)
```

you have your data structured like this:

```
In: df
Out: 
            open  high   low  close
2018-05-05  2.75  2.05  2.67   2.92
2018-05-08  2.93  2.97  2.79   2.84
2018-05-09  2.46  2.74  2.45   2.69
2018-05-10  2.69  2.69  2.21   2.33
```

And then, you can resample your time index which aggregates your data per month. To get a value per month, you only have to tell how you want the numbers being condensed - in your case you wanted min- and max-values:

```
In: df.resample('M').min()
Out: 
            open  high   low  close
2018-05-31  2.46  2.05  2.21   2.33

In: df.resample('M').max()
Out: 
            open  high   low  close
2018-05-31  2.93  2.97  2.79   2.92
```

However, you can also apply other statistical functions of interest, like `sum()`, `mean()` or `std()`:

```
In: df.resample('M').sum()
Out: 
             open   high    low  close
2018-05-31  10.83  10.45  10.12  10.78

In: df.resample('M').mean()
Out: 
              open    high   low  close
2018-05-31  2.7075  2.6125  2.53  2.695

In: df.resample('M').std()
Out: 
                open      high       low     close
2018-05-31  0.193972  0.394324  0.255604  0.261343
```

And if you want the max-value per month over all columns, you can apply another max()-function, with respect to the other axis:

```
In: df.resample('M').max().apply(max, 1)
Out: 
2018-05-31    2.97
```

analog with min:

```
In: df.resample('M').min().apply(min, 1)
Out: 
2018-05-31    2.05
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I have started to learn pandas and it is a great tool and makes what I need to do much easier.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR version of the thing above:

```
import pandas as pd
```

If you don't know pandas, I highly suggest reading up about it. ([The cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#pandas-cookbook) is amazing!)

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.resample('M').first()
```

Then additionally to the answer above here, **you do never wan't to take the mean of your dataset in financial data.** I recently had a large discussion with the traders at my fund about this and this will include minute spikes or morning and  afternoon volatilty/volume which you don't want as you are working with a monthly frequency.

Comment: The original question was about getting min- and max- values of monthly resampled data, which I answered. I just gave a hint that as an example some well known further statistical functions can easily be applied the same way like `min`and `max`. Who is interested in what is not my problem and I would recommend a careful use of words like 'never' or 'always' with regards to other peoples needs. However, I don't see what `df.resample('M').first()` has to do with the question - except for being an additional example in the list of available functions...

Comment: It sounds like you feel offended, I am merely giving my opinion on the matter and what one should and should not do with financial data. I did not mean to offend you, only to help.

Comment: Well, offended is too much, thanks for asking, but I have to admit that I was surprised seeing the very same idea to solve the problem (pd -> df.resample) but not adressing the min/max-part of the question as a new answer - decorated with a comment what my answer lacks. I think I just tend to receive such absolute phrases ('never') printed in bold  too  personally. Perhaps if I were you, i just had accepted that the Ida was already writtenand would have added the comment as such under the existing answer.